# Excel connection cannot find tables unless document is open

Tags: excel, ssis, connection

I have a Excel (.xls) file that I open with an Excel connection manager in SSIS. This week I've suddenly encountered an issue (it has never happened before) where the connection manager cannot find the tables in the Excel document unless I open (and keep open) the document first.

The error message is: 
Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager 1'.
Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager 1'

I've tried changing the Run64BitRuntime to False, but same issue. I've also tried recreating the workbook, creating a new connection manager and trying a different excel save version.

Any ideas what 1) caused the problem and 2) how to solve it?

Comment: Do you get an error?  What have you tried so far? If you thought changing `Run64BitRuntime` would make a difference then there is obviously more to this story than you've shared.  Have you tried removing and recreating the connection, or an alternate workbook, for troubleshooting reasons?

Comment: Added more detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It really worked for me when I was trying with the client. I was facing the same error `Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager 1'. Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager 1'`. 
I keep open the excel file with .xls and then select the Microsoft Excel version as 97-2003 in connection manager.Then select the file from the drop down in the excel source.You will be able to see the file there now.